# old get view change data in other listview

Tags: android, listview

hello every one i am really struck from last 3 days in a very tiny place i have 3 custom listview in my application what does my application is when i check value in one listvew and then scoll other list view the data of first edit box automatically pass to other and i dont want that . . my first adapter

```
public class Doneyesadapter extends BaseAdapter {



       private List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private PackageManager pm;
        ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;
        private Context ctx;
        int[] visiblePosArray;
        private volatile int positionCheck;


        String[] strItecode=null;
        String[] strItem;
        String[] strQuantity,text;
        int temp;
        private int editingPosition = 0;

        ArrayList<String> listItem;
        ArrayList<String> listAddress;
        ArrayList<String> quantity;
        ArrayList<String> idlist;

        public static ArrayList<String> ItemID_list=new ArrayList<String>();
        public static ArrayList<String> StockCode_list=new ArrayList<String>();
        public static ArrayList<String> Description_list=new ArrayList<String>();
        public static ArrayList<String> Quantity_list=new ArrayList<String>();



        Context mContext;
        ArrayList<String> dates;

        //constructor
        public Doneyesadapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> listItem, ArrayList<String> listAddress,ArrayList<String> quantity
                ,ArrayList<String> idlist ) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.listItem = listItem;
            this.listAddress = listAddress;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.idlist = idlist;

            text= new String[idlist.size()];


            pm = mContext.getPackageManager();

            positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(listItem.size());
            for(int i =0;i<listItem.size();i++){
                positionArray.add(false);
            }
            //this.dates=date;


        }

        private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                text[editingPosition] = s.toString();
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        };

        public int getCount() {
            return listItem.size();
        }
        public void cleardata(){

            listAddress.clear();
            listItem.clear();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        public String getName(int pos){
            int name =pos;
            String ll = listAddress.get(name);
            return ll;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            final ViewHolder1 holder;
            temp=position;
            if (arg1 == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder1();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklistcustom, viewGroup, false);
                holder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) arg1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
                holder.Des = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.description1);
                holder.stockid = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.stockid1);
                holder.done = (EditText) arg1.findViewById(R.id.quantity1);
                holder.stockid.setText(listItem.get(position));
                holder.Des.setText(listAddress.get(position));
                holder.done.setText(quantity.get(position));


                arg1.setTag(holder);
            } else {


                holder = (ViewHolder1) arg1.getTag();
            }



                holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);


                holder.checkbox1.setFocusable(false);
                // holder.checkbox1.setImageDrawable(appInfoList.get(position).loadIcon(pm));
                holder.checkbox1.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
    //        holder.checkbox1.setText(appInfoList.get(position).loadLabel(pm));
                holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                        int i = 0;
                        // Toast.makeText(mContext, "here is commom"+buttonView, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (holder.checkbox1.isChecked()) {
                            quantity.set(position,holder.done.getText().toString());

                            positionArray.set(position, true);
                            String id, qu, des, stc;
                            id = idlist.get(position);
                            qu = quantity.get(position);
                            des = listAddress.get(position);
                            stc = listItem.get(position);

                            ItemID_list.add(i, id);
                            StockCode_list.add(i, stc);
                            Description_list.add(des);
                            Quantity_list.add(i,text[temp]);
                            quantity.set(position,holder.done.getText().toString());
                            holder.done.setText(quantity.get(position));


                            i++;


                        } else {
                            positionArray.set(position, false);


                            ItemID_list.remove(i);
                            StockCode_list.remove(i);
                            Description_list.remove(i);
                            Quantity_list.remove(i);
                            holder.done.setText(quantity.get(position));
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                });


                holder.done.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        text[temp] = s.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        text[temp] = s.toString();
                    }
                });
                holder.done.setText(text[temp]);

                //date.setText(dates);

            holder.stockid.setText(listItem.get(position));
            holder.Des.setText(listAddress.get(position));
            holder.done.setText(quantity.get(position));
                return arg1;

        }
        private class ViewHolder1{
            CheckBox checkbox1;
            TextView Des;
            TextView stockid;
            EditText done;


        }
    }
```

my second adapter

```
 public Doneyesadapter2(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> listItem, ArrayList<String> listAddress,ArrayList<String> quantity
   ,ArrayList<String> idlist ) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listItem = listItem;
        this.listAddress = listAddress;
        this.quantitys = quantity;
        this.idlist = idlist;
        text= new String[idlist.size()];


        pm = mContext.getPackageManager();

        positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(listItem.size());
        for(int i =0;i<listItem.size();i++){
            positionArray.add(false);
        }
        //this.dates=date;


    }
    private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            text[editingPosition] = s.toString();
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }
    public void cleardata(){

        listAddress.clear();
        listItem.clear();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public String getName(int pos){
        int name =pos;
        String ll = listAddress.get(name);
        return ll;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View arg11, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolders2 holder;
        int a=3;
        Log.e("second getview called", String.valueOf(a));

        temp=position;
        if (arg11 == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolders2();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             arg11 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stocklistcustom2, viewGroup, false);
            holder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) arg11.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
            holder.Des = (TextView) arg11.findViewById(R.id.description2);
            holder.stockid = (TextView) arg11.findViewById(R.id.stockid2);
            holder.done = (EditText) arg11.findViewById(R.id.quantity2);

            holder.stockid.setText(listItem.get(position));
            holder.Des.setText(listAddress.get(position));
            holder.done.setText(quantitys.get(position));
            arg11.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolders2) arg11.getTag();


        }
            holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);




            holder.checkbox1.setFocusable(false);
            // holder.checkbox1.setImageDrawable(appInfoList.get(position).loadIcon(pm));
            holder.checkbox1.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
            holder.checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int i = 0;
                    if (holder.checkbox1.isChecked()) {
                        quantitys.set(position,holder.done.getText().toString());
                        positionArray.set(position, true);
                        String id, qu, des, stc;
                        id = idlist.get(position);
                        qu = quantitys.get(position);
                        des = listAddress.get(position);
                        stc = listItem.get(position);

                        ItemID_list2.add(i, id);
                        StockCode_list2.add(i, stc);
                        Description_list2.add(des);
                        //Quantity_list2.add(, holder.done.getText().toString());
                        Quantity_list2.add(i,holder.done.getText().toString());
                        i++;
                        general=i;


                    } else {
                        positionArray.set(position, false);
                        ItemID_list2.remove(i);
                        StockCode_list2.remove(i);
                        Description_list2.remove(i);
                        Quantity_list2.remove(i);

                        i--;
                        general=i;
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.done.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    text[temp] = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    text[temp] = s.toString();
                }
            });
            holder.done.setText(text[temp]);


        holder.stockid.setText(listItem.get(position));
        holder.Des.setText(listAddress.get(position));
        holder.done.setText(quantitys.get(position));

        //date.setText(dates);



        return arg11;
    }
        private class ViewHolders2{
            CheckBox checkbox1;
            TextView Des;
            TextView stockid;
            EditText done;


        }
}
```

Comment: You are probably passing the same list to both the adapter, in this way you are basically passing the reference to the list. Both adapter will act on the same list and a change in one list will result in a change in the other list, because they basically are the same